# Flutter : set background image for Painter class

Tags: dart, flutter, background-image, paint

I need to set a background image for [Painter Widget](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/painter) because I'm trying to build a widget that will helps kids to draw numbers and letter over my background image.

This will be the default widget background:

[image: Painter Background]

After loading the widget the kids should be able to draw over the background.

I have tried to modify the body of the scaffold from the official Painter plugin [example](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/painter#-example-tab-) but the image not appears in the background of the painter it show only blank screen.

```
Container(
    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
      image: new DecorationImage(
        image: new ExactAssetImage('assets/test.png'),
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
    ),
    child: Painter(_controller),
  )
```

Is it possiple to set a background image for the Painter widget ? if not are there any other solution could help me to achieve my task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use a `transparent` background Color for the `Painter`

```
PainterController _controller;
    @override
    void initState() {
      _controller = PainterController();
      _controller.thickness = 5.0;
      _controller.backgroundColor = Colors.transparent;
      super.initState();
    }
```

and that's it.

Comment: Don't worry, remember try to read the source code of the librar you are using to check how it works.